# Text - empty text node Problems

Tags: asp.net, html, css, browser

I have asp.net buttons rendered on the browser which are in different lines. I assume this Text- Empty text node is because of that. Since buttons are displayed in different lines, on the all the browsers I noticed a small space. How can I clear this? I dont have any css that adds this space.

If I remove the  line spacing in the editor. I dont see any space, but i can't do it because of the formatting the code.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnButton1" text = "Button1"/> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnButton1" text = "Button1"/>
```

Comment: Show us the aspx and rendered html, perhaps an additional screenshot.

Comment: <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnButton1" text = "Button1"/> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnButton1" text = "Button1"/>                   other one with both the buttons in the same line

Comment: This is one of the things about asp.net that can drive someone crazy. It has been my experience that you have to remove the line spaces in the editor and just deal with the poor format.

Comment: I think I just have to deal with it. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons to be positioned next to each other, with no space in between them, you can consider using the CSS `float` rule:

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
  <asp:Button runat="server" style="float: left" ... />
  <asp:Button runat="server" style="float: left"  ... />
</div>
```

The `<div>` element will contain both buttons, and any elements after it will be on a new line. The buttons inside the `<div>` will move as far left as possible, and no space will exist between them.

Demo (not ASP.NET, but works just as well): http://jsfiddle.net/vDWCn/1/

Comment: That works for this case. I have different case. I actual wanted the space. Just figuring why that space is coming.